# C Reg Ex Library code help

Tags: c, regex

I'm trying out the C RegEx Library. This is the code I've written for testing example patterns and strings. However, this only prints out a single pattern per string. For eg in this case when I run the code it only prints out "asd f g ". It does not recognize "xty y z ".
Is there anything wrong with my code or some fundamental mistake in my understanding of how the library works. Any and all help would be appreciated.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    regmatch_t arr[10];
    regex_t *reg=malloc(sizeof(regex_t));
    char *str="\t\t  asd f g  \t   =\t\t  xty y z \t   \t";

    if(regcomp(reg,"[a-z][a-z ]*",REG_EXTENDED | REG_NEWLINE))
        printf("Unsuccessful Compilation\n");
    int i,j;
    int status=regexec(reg,str,10,arr,0);
    if(status)
    {   
        printf("Match Not Found\n");
        return;
    }   
    else
        printf("Match found\n");

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i].rm_so!=-1)
            {
                j=arr[i].rm_so;
                printf(":");
                while(j<arr[i].rm_eo)
                {
                    printf("%c",str[j]);
                    j++;
                }
                printf(":\nNewline\n");
            } 
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe regexec has to be called multiple times, basically it will stop on the first match.

Comment: Also you need a regfree() on the regular expression to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @Sasquiha -Yes,calling regexec multiple times should do the trick. Though like Henno Brandsma has mentioned in his answer, I will have to probably match the string the first time with regexec, then trim the string after the last character of the previous match using the previous rm_eo, then call regexec again until either there is no more string left or no more matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what arr does. `arr[0]` contains the match, and `arr[1]` and onwards will contain matches for subexpressions that you matched (bracketed ones). `regexec` will only match once, and you will need to repeat it in a loop, continuing while `regexec` matches 0, e.g., and starting the next match one further than the rm_so of the previous match.
You then need only one element in the `arr` array, as you have no nested expressions.

But e.g. if you wanted to match both sides on the equal sign, you could use the regex `([a-z][a-z ]*).*=.*([a-z][a-z ]*)` and then after a match `arr[0]` would be a struct that describes the whole match, and `arr[1]` one that describes the one before the = sign and `arr[2]` the one after (the bracketed subexpressions). So if you only want to match lines as the example, you can effectively use subexpressions.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma-Thanks for that wonderful answer. I guess I need to improve my understanding of how regular expressions are matched. Any links or books on that topic? Also the first para of your answer, _continuing while regcomp matches 0_ - you mean regexec right? Also, _one further than the rm so_ -I guess that should be rm_eo? After reading your answer, I dug further on how those data structures are filled. Came across this link which explains the intricacies [Using Registers](http://docs.freebsd.org/info/regex/regex.info.Using_Registers.html). Thanks again for you answer!

Comment: yes, regexec, indeed. I'll fix it. There is an O' Reilly book (Mastering Regular Expressions) which could be useful, but it's more oriented towards Perl/Python etc, but also contains lots of general info.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma - Please have a look at my comment to Sasquiha in my original post. I hope that is what you meant in the first para of your answer. The alternative that you have mentioned in the 2ns para, actually would work better for me. I didn't know it could be done that way.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma-Today I was thinking about the regular expression that you had posted for matching both sides of '='.I have a couple of questions.
1. The regex you have designed will( andcorrect me if I'm wrong) match trailing blank spaces too. Right?
2. If I had a statement like xxx|yyyy = zzzz, then the regex would not match at all and rightly so. However, if I had a statement xxx = yyyy|zzzz. Then yyyy would match on the RHS. However, most likely this would have been a typo on the user's end and I want to throw an error. How do I detect this?
@Sasquiha-I'd appreciate your input too.

Comment: I didn't know whether to post this as a separate question or not. Hence have asked you this question here. If you'd recommend it, I'll post it as a separate question too.

Comment: What is it exactly what you want to match? I'd post a separate question asking a regex that matches this, but not that etc.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma - Thanks for that advice. I'll post it soon as a separate question. Thanks again!